# Can't access nested object in blade template

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-blade

I'm using Laravel, Eloquent for queries, and Blade for templating.

Here are the models I'm working with:

```
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class DistrictCharge extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'plan_year', 'location_id', 'meal_id', 'charge_id', 'price' ];

    public function plan_year() {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\PlanYear', 'plan_year');
    }
}


namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class PlanYear extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [ 'year', 'start_date', 'end_date' ];

    public $primaryKey = 'year';
}
```

Relevant controller code:

```
public function index()
{
    $district_charges = DistrictCharge::with('plan_year')->get();

    return view('district-charges/index', compact(
        'district_charges',
    ));
}
```

In my template, when I do this:

```
{{ $district_charges[0] }}
```

I get this (indented for readability):

```
{
    "id":1,
    "created_at":"2017-01-23 21:33:53",
    "updated_at":"2017-01-23 21:33:53",
    "plan_year": {
        "year":2016,
        "start_date":"2015-07-01",
        "end_date":"2016-06-30",
        "created_at":"2017-01-23 21:03:08",
        "updated_at":"2017-01-23 21:03:08"
    },
    "location_id":"2",
    "meal_id":"1",
    "charge_id":"4",
    "price":"175"
}
```

This makes sense; the `plan_year` field is populated with the contents of the database entry it refers to, exactly as I want. But when I do this:

```
{{ $district_charges[0]->plan_year }}
```

I just get `2016`, a non-object. This is a problem because I queried in order to populate the `plan_year` field because I need the `start_date` and `end_date` fields that it comes with for my view. When I try to access these properties in my view I just get a 'trying to get properties of a non-object' error. I'm not that familiar with Laravel, Eloquent, or Blade, so any help would be great.

Edit:

Table structure as requested:

```
district_charges
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| created_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| updated_at  | timestamp        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| plan_year   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| location_id | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| meal_id     | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| charge_id   | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| price       | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

plan_years
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field      | Type      | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| year       | int(11)   | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| start_date | date      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| end_date   | date      | NO   |     | NULL    |       |
| created_at | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| updated_at | timestamp | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+------------+-----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

What I'm not getting is why I can see the contents of the variable I want when I output the whole thing in a template, but when I selectively output just parts of it, it says it doesn't exist.

Comment: Can you post the table structure of both tables?

Comment: That looks like a JSONString, is that what blade expects?

Comment: @RiggsFolly that's the output from Blade when I just dump out the whole variable, so I can't speak to how it's handled internally. The thing I'm not understanding is why I can **see** the entire variable, including the nested object I want to use, but when I try to **access** that nested object's properties, I get an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have any id in the table, so put the following class member in your PlanYear model

```
protected $primaryKey = 'year';
```

Also, change your relation method to be without an underscore - for example, `year()`

Comment: Before I had `public $primaryKey = 'year';` in the PlanYear model. I changed it to `protected` but am getting the same results. Does it require some kind of manual restructuring of the table itself?

Comment: It's hard to find the bug without debugging it, but my assumption is that it is related to the fact that you link two tables with a number which is not an id. The correct way to structure your DB is to add an incremental id to the play_year table, and put year_id field in the district_charges table. Then your relation command will be `return $this->belongsTo('App\PlanYear')` and you won't need to override the primaryKey of the model

Comment: That makes sense (given my limited knowledge of this framework), but it's unfortunate because I was hoping I could use the year as the unique identifier and might have a bit of a tangle to sort through going back and redoing the table and the other tables that relate to it.

Comment: The template obviously has access in some form to the populated `plan_year` field, since it outputs the whole thing when I just put the whole variable in the template. Why is this, and why can't I access it directly when it's there?

Comment: I tried populating and using another field, `location_id`, and the `locations` table does have a proper primary key, which I'm pretty sure I'm referencing correctly, and I have the exact same thing happening. I can view the entire object, but when I try to get the contents of the nested object I get an error.

Comment: Which kind of error? Post the code of the other example and the entire error

Comment: I get the same 'trying to access property of a non-object' error, because the field is just a string in the object Blade is working with, apparently. I'll come back to the problem with more example code, because I want to understand this, but for now I've done a hack where I open a `@php` block and  `json_decode` the output of the entire variable (because it gives me the populated field I want) and then use that to access the properties I want.

Comment: The only thing that we didn't check is that the relation method name has underscore. Try to change your relation to year()

Comment: Yes! I didn't know about the underscore problem. Changing the relation function from `plan_year` to 'year` worked. Thank you. I don't know how to mark this comment as the correct answer, though :P

Answer (score 0):

```
 public function plan_year() {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\PlanYear', 'plan_year','year');
}
```

I believe year is a primary key in your table

I believe you have a data in your tables otherwise you will get fatal error

```
$district_charges[0]->plan_year->start_date
```

for showing end Date you need to do the same

```
$district_charges[0]->plan_year-> end_date
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. When I add `{{ $district_charges[0]->plan_year->start_date }}` to my template I get the same 'trying to get property of non-object' error.

Comment: @keekeejeejee i have edited my answer please take a look

Comment: I added the `return $this->belongsTo('App\PlanYear', 'plan_year','year');` you suggested, but with no success.

Comment: @keekeejeejee please DistrictCharge::with('plan_year')->toSql(); and see what it gives you?

Comment: you have a error in your relation thats why the query is not working fine